# How to use WordPress update_post_meta with JSON string?

Tags: php, mysql, json, wordpress, woocommerce

I have this WooCommerce shop that I have to integrate with an external stock system. Therefore I need to create/update products through PHP/WordPress. This part i have figured out.
Problem is the product variations. They are stored in the database as JSON strings.

Example:

```
a:1:{s:10:"size";a:6:{s:4:"name";s:10:"Size";s:5:"value";s:17:"42";s:8:"position";s:1:"0";s:10:"is_visible";i:1;s:12:"is_variation";i:1;s:11:"is_taxonomy";i:0;}}
```

However, when i insert it like this

```
update_post_meta($product_id, '_product_attributes', 'a:1:{s:10:"size....');
```

It adds `s:173:"  a:1:{s:10:"siz....  ";`

I have tried with json_encode() which removes the "s:173" but keeps the double quotes at the beginning and end.

Any help on how to store this JSON string without the additional stuff? Would be much appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're seeing in the database is a serialised array. The post meta functions handle all of this for you.

Use get_post_meta to get the array and simply pass in the array to update_post_meta.

You don't need to use serialize / unserialize functions.

Comment: It really doesn't make sense why it would do that, but it seem to work anyway. Actually it's a nice feature, once you know about it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

I have found some code in woocommerce plugin,

You can do something like this:-

```
$attributes['size'] = array(
    'name'          => "Size",
    'value'         => "42",
    'position'      => "0",
    'is_visible'    => 1,
    'is_variation'  => 1,
    'is_taxonomy'   => 0
);

update_post_meta( $post_id, '_product_attributes', $attributes );
```

Hope this help you...